# Custom options for a Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type called "Product" with 2 custom fields "Size" and "Color" , I would like the "Size" to be limited to "Small", "Medium" and "Large" , How to I create this list of pre specified values which show up in a Custom Meta box populating an option field ?

Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution will be using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, I guess.

You can easily add custom write panels with it and limit them only for some posts based on post type, template file, etc.

If you'd like to do implement it yourself, then you'll have to add your custom meta box using [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function.

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek , this was an interview question and was trying to figure out the best option.

Comment: :) No problem :)